# How do I save a JSON file with four spaces indentation using JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I need to read a JSON configuration file, modify a value and then save the modified JSON back to the file again. The JSON is as simple as it gets:

```
{
    "test": "init",
    "revision": 0
}
```

To load the data and modify the value I do this:

```
var config = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("config.json"));
config["revision"] = 1;
```

So far so good; now, to write the JSON back to the file. First I tried this:

```
File.WriteAllText("config.json", config.ToString(Formatting.Indented));
```

Which writes the file correctly, but the indentation is only two spaces.

```
{
  "test": "init",
  "revision": 1
}
```

From the documentation, it looks like there's no way to pass any other options in using this method, so I tried modifying [this example](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/14/writing-json-to-a-file-using-json-net) which would allow me to directly set the `Indentation` and `IndentChar` properties of the `JsonTextWriter` to specify the amount of indentation:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open("config.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        using (JsonTextWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            jw.IndentChar = ' ';
            jw.Indentation = 4;

            jw.WriteRaw(config.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to have any effect: the file is still written with two space indentation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `config.ToString()`, so the object is already serialised into a string and formatted when you write it using the `JsonTextWriter`.

Use a serialiser to serialise the object to the writer instead:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(jw, config);
```

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue and found out that WriteRaw does not effect the indentation settings, however you can solve the issue using WriteTo on the JObject

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open("config.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        using (JsonTextWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            jw.IndentChar = ' ';
            jw.Indentation = 4;

            config.WriteTo(jw);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the code example being more complete!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to feed a tab character to the IndentChar?

```
...    
jw.IndentChar = '\t';
...
```

Accordinging to the documentation, it should use the tab character to indent the JSON instead of the space character.
http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Formatting.htm

Comment: Not really what I was looking for I'm afraid. The question specifically asks for space indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I summarize the complete code, based on [@Guffa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25788934/1051244).

Changed from `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` to `FileMode.Create`. Otherwise the file will not be shortened when the new contents are smaller.

```
var config = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("config.json"));
config["revision"] = 1;

using (FileStream fs = File.Open("config.json", FileMode.Create))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        using (JsonTextWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            jw.IndentChar = ' ';
            jw.Indentation = 4;

            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(jw, config);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you have an extension method that makes json easy to read for human.
It removes quotes in property names, converts enums to strings and indent json with 4 spaces.

```
public static string ToPrettyJson(this object obj)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented, new StringEnumConverter());
    json = Regex.Replace(json, @"^([\s]+)""([^""]+)"": ", "$1$2: ", RegexOptions.Multiline); // no quotes in props
    json = Regex.Replace(json, @"^[ ]+", m => new String(' ', m.Value.Length * 2), RegexOptions.Multiline); // more indent spaces
    return json;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don`t have a class to serialize/deserialize your JSON object, you may use JObject from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

```
var buildText = JObject.Parse(buildInfo.ToString());
File.WriteAllText(infoPath, buildText.ToString());
```

As a result you will have fully formatted .json file