# Customize identation parameter in JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

The default ident in Json.Net seems to be 2 spaces:

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonString, Formatting.Indented);
```

For clarity I want to change it to 4 spaces, but I don't seem to find the right way to apply the property. It seems that it exists, since I have found some similar code (direct link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788686/how-do-i-save-a-json-file-with-four-spaces-indentation-using-json-net)):

```
using (JsonTextWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    jw.IndentChar = ' ';
    jw.Indentation = 4;

    jw.WriteRaw(config.ToString());
}
```

...except that, if possible, I would preffer to avoid having to unnecessarily deal with streams in this case.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Side note - Could you please say why you care about the amount of spaces in your JSON?

Comment: Readability, to editing the json. Also as a side note, I have been trying to find better ways to edit the json with c#, but the few solutions I have found seem to time-consuming, plus I am not sure that the final result will fit my needs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would create a utility class which serializes it with the right indentation, similar to how `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` does it:

```
public static class JsonConvertEx
{
    public static string SerializeObject<T>(T value)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
        using (JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            jsonWriter.IndentChar = ' ';
            jsonWriter.Indentation = 4;

            jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, value, typeof(T));
        }

        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

And consume it like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var anon = new { Name = "Yuval", Age = 1 };
        var result = JsonConvertEx.SerializeObject(anon);
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like there could be a simpler (but clearly not easy to find) solution integrated in the framework, but your code does the trick indeed so I am marking it as answered.

Comment: @XavierPeña I've looked around a bit in the Json.NET code, didn't see anything sticking out.