# Json.NET object serialization - change indent char

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have simple code to serialise my object into JSON:

```
 Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject, Formatting.Indented)
```

How can I change indent char to "-" in resulting JSON? I know there is `JsonTextWriter.IndentChar` but I have no clue how to implement it together with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an answer in the linked question below from Yuval Itzchakov that creates a `JsonTextWriter`, sets an `IndentChar` and then serializes with the modified settings. Here's that code rewritten in VB and using the requested '-' char.

```
Sub Main
    Dim anon = New With { .Name = "Yuval", .Age = 1 }
    Dim result = SerializeObject(anon)

    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub

Public Function SerializeObject(Of t)(ByVal arg As t) As String

    Dim sw = New StringWriter()

    Using jsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)
        jsonWriter.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
        jsonWriter.IndentChar = "-"C
        jsonWriter.Indentation = 4

        Dim jsonSerializer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.CreateDefault()
        jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, arg)
    End Using

    Return sw.ToString()

End Function
```

**Results**

```
{
----"Name": "Yuval",
----"Age": 1
}
```

Source: [Customize indentation parameter in JsonConvert.SerializeObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33100640/84369)