# Is there a way to use a custom indentation character with the Json.Net JsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I need to change the way the `JsonSerializer` indents to use tabs instead of 2 spaces... Is this possible?

I can turn indentation on as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947005/how-to-turn-on-indentation-when-writing-json-using-json-net).

My code looks something like this:

```
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer
{
    Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
};

using (var fs = File.Create(fileName))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    jsonSerializer.Serialize(sw, data);
}
```

---

Note: this is a different question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788686/how-do-i-save-a-json-file-with-four-spaces-indentation-using-json-net) one describes a method with the `JsonTextWriter` - I want to do it with `JsonSerializer` if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [a custom JsonWriter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonWriter.htm).

```
using (var fs = File.Create("data.json"))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
using (var jtw = new JsonTextWriter(sw) { 
  Formatting= Formatting.Indented, 
  Indentation=3, 
  IndentChar = '\t'}) {
  (new JsonSerializer()).Serialize(jtw, data);
}
```